# $emit an event when clicking on an element

Tags: angularjs

Is there a built-in directive, like `ng-click`, that emits an event instead of calling a function? I want to do something like this:

HTML:

```
<button ng-click-emit="foo" ng-click-emit-model="model.bar">Emit foo</button>
```

Child controller:

```
$scope.model = {bar: 'baz'};
```

Parent controller:

```
$scope.$on('foo', function(event, arg) {
    console.log(arg); // prints 'baz'
});
```

Answer (score 14):

I figured it out: just call the scope's `$emit` function directly from `ng-click`. So the HTML in my example would become:

```
<button ng-click="$emit('foo', model.bar)">Emit foo</button>
```

The same should work for `$broadcast` too.